# How to a navigate inside a File Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

[Click here to see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Dcz.png)

I am trying to go inside a File Object to read the file using JQuery or Javascript, but I don't know how to go inside the 0. Any suggestions?

Comment: whatever[0] ?????

Comment: If you see the image, is the first element. Is a single 0, with no name.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Is "the element that I am trying to read"[0]. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to access the `DOM` element property of a jQuery object? And not get the `File` of a `FileList` object? Note, a `DOM` element is not a `File` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.files`  property of an `<input type="file">` element to get the `FileList` object, generally within `change` event handler

```html
<input type="file" accepts="image/*">
<script>
  var input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
  input.onchange = function(event) {
    console.log(input.files, input.files[0], input.files[0] instanceof File);
  }
</script>
```